# ILIKE and NOT ILIKE in aws redshift different from total

Tags: sql, count, null, amazon-redshift

I ran three following queries in amazon redshift:

```
select count(*)  
from t1
```

The count was 1554.

```
select count(*)  
from t1  
where  
    item_name ilike "blue"
```

The count was 62.

```
select count(*)  
from t1  
where  
    item_name not ilike "blue"
```

The count was 85.

The last two (62 + 85) should equal 1554. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double-quotes are for identifiers: `"myColumn"`
Single quotes are for values: `'value'`.

Your examples contradict those [basic syntax rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Also, you did not consider `NULL` values, which neither qualify with:

```
item_name ilike 'blue'
```

nor with:

```
item_name not ilike 'blue'
```

What do you get for:

```
SELECT count(*)                             AS all_rows
     , count(item_name  ~~* 'blue' OR NULL) AS item_name_blue
     , count(item_name !~~* 'blue' OR NULL) AS item_name_not_blue
     , count(item_name)                     AS item_name_not_null
     , count(item_name IS NULL OR NULL)     AS item_name_null
FROM   t1;
```

`~~*`  .. internal Postgres operator for `ILIKE`
`!~~*` .. internal Postgres operator for `NOT ILIKE`
(Careful: slightly different operator precedence.)

Comment: Thanks.  double quotes was a typo in the question.  once I added null that made up the difference.

Comment: For anyone using this as a reference point, the `~~*` operator corresponds to `ILIKE`, rather than `LIKE` according to PostgreSQL docs 9.7.1.

Comment: @John: Thank you, I fixed the typo. (Aside: there is no Postgres version 9.7.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good catch! I was apparently referring to the section number *9.7.1* within the Postgres 12.4 documentation.